# cisco small business 300-10 managed config import fails

Tags: cisco, switch, copy, image, networking

Device: cisco small business 300-10 10-Port Gigabit Managed Switch

Firmware:   1.2.7.76

The config installation via webinterface with TFTP or http fails with following message in the console interface:

```
CSB-99#19-Jul-2012 19:58:21 %AAA-I-CONNECT: New http connection for user cisco, source 10.10.6.1 destination 10.10.6.99 ACCEPTED
19-Jul-2012 19:59:49 %COPY-I-FILECPY: Files Copy - source URL tftp://10.10.6.1/config.txt destination URL running-config
19-Jul-2012 20:00:50 %AAA-I-DISCONNECT: http connection for user cisco, source 10.10.6.1 destination 10.10.6.99 TERMINATED
19-Jul-2012 20:01:06 %TFTP-N-TIMERSEND: Session is closed after timeout is expired
19-Jul-2012 20:01:06 %COPY-W-TRAP: The copy operation has failed
```

In the Webinterface is following message:

```
Bytes Transferred: 11264
Status: copy failed
Error message: Copy: Copy completed with errors.
```

It seems he tries to copy the configuration file but in the running-config are unreasonable configrations.

I have tried importing a working image from another device with the same type and firmware. In my opinion the problem is not the config file.

Any Solutions? Thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have directly copied the configuration file via the webinterface to the startup-config.
With a reload the config is not messed up.